# class org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext cannot be cast to class org.apache.camel.ExtendedCamelContext

Tags: java, spring, jboss, apache-camel

I am trying to implement a web service on JBoss 7.3, my dependencies are the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-camel-subsystem-core</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My CamelContext is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<bean class="MyBean" id="helloBean"/>

<route id="_route1">
    <from id="_from1" uri="direct:start"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <bean method="sayHi(*)" ref="helloBean"/>
    <log message="After Bean: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
</route>

</beans>
```

When the service is invoked, the error above appears, along with:

(org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext is in unnamed module of loader 'org.apache.camel.spring@2.23.2.fuse-780036-redhat-00001')

Comment: If you're using Red Hat Fuse on EAP, then you should import the org.jboss.redhat-fuse:fuse-eap-bom into your maven project. Instead of manually defining the Camel component dependency versions. Camel 3.x is not supported on Red Hat Fuse on EAP, hence why you get the error. Refer to the Fuse 'Deploying into JBoss EAP' documentation for more information.

Comment: If Camel 3.x is not supported on Red Hat Fuse on EAP, what do i need to download in order for 3.x to work?